# Spring Boot doesn't create automatic configuration for database from application.properties

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-boot

I have followed [a guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) for creating simple spring boot app with JPA and when application was completed it should have created database connection based on configuration from application.properties file, however it didn't happen (I get *Not an managed type* exceptions). I know this is issuse with application.properties file because app runs correctly when I configure it manually like [here](http://www.baeldung.com/2011/12/13/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-3-1-and-jpa/).

Project structure:
[image: Project structure]

**POM.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>demo.tomek</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringMVC</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**application.properties file:**

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TEST?createIfNotExists=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=but

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

# Enable spring data repos 
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.template.cache=false
```

**static void main()**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("demo")
@EnableJpaRepositories("demo")
public class SpringBootTEST {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(SpringBootTEST.class, args);

        ProductService pRepo = ctx.getBean("productService", ProductService.class);
        pRepo.addSomeProducts();
        CustomerService cRepo = ctx.getBean("customerService", CustomerService.class);
        cRepo.addSomeCustomers();
    }
}
```

Let me stress it again: everything works fine when I configure it manually like here: http://www.baeldung.com/2011/12/13/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-3-1-and-jpa/

I run out of ideas...

Comment: Move your `SpringBootTEST` class to the `demo` package remove all annotation but the `@SpringBootApplication` and restart.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried it... and it also worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your entities are not in a subpackage of your application class, you also have to add the following annotation to `SpringBootTEST` so that Hibernate can scan your entity classes:

```
@EntityScan("demo.database")
```

Alternatively, it should also work, if you specify the package in the `SpringBootApplication` annotation:

```
@SpringBootApplication("demo")
```

Then you should also be able to remove the custom `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation.

Comment: I was thinking @ComponentScan will handle it. I tried to delete other annotations also but it didnt work and I had to leave them as they were.